# Geb set value of input, with default value appending

Tags: geb

I am trying to set a value in my test to the input below which has a default value

```
    <input type="text" name="ntsSellAmount" maxlength="7" size="8" tabindex="130" value="0.0">
```

It seems when I set the value in my Geb page it is appended to the default value 0.00300:

```
    grossExTax {
        $("#content > form:nth-child(3) > fieldset:nth-child(8) > table:nth-child(3) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(10) > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")
    }

    grossExTax.value("300")
```

Is there a way to clear the field and then set the value overriding the default value 0.00

Comment: If you have access to jquery try grossExTax.jquery.val("300")

Answer (score 7):

According to [section 4.13.5 of the manual](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#text-inputs-and-textareas), what you're doing is right.

`value('foo')` should overwrite, whilst `<<` should append.

They have an example at section [4.12 Form Control Shortcuts](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#form-control-shortcuts)

> Interacting with form controls (input, select etc.) is such a common task in web functional testing that Geb provides convenient shortcuts for common functions.
>
> Geb supports the following shortcuts for dealing with form controls.
>
> Consider the following HTML…
>
>
>     `<form>
>         <input type="text" name="geb" value="testing" />
>     </form>`
>
>
>
> The value can be read and written via property notation…
>
>
>     `$("form").geb == "testing"
>     $("form").geb = "goodness"
>     $("form").geb == "goodness"`
>
>
> These are literally shortcuts for…
>
>
>     `$("form").find("input", name: "geb").value() == "testing"
>     $("form").find("input", name: "geb").value("goodness")
>     $("form").find("input", name: "geb").value() == "goodness"`

With that in mind, have you tried: `grossExTax.value = 300`?

Comment: ... have you verified `grossExTax` is actually the div you're after?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly mention the page you are in before trying to set the value on the locator. Try something like below

```
at GrossExTaxPage // This is the Geb page object where you have defined the element
grossExTax.value("300")
```